# 404 error after installing PHP on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis, installation, php-manager

I have installed PHP manager. But then when I try to access PHPinfo. I got the following screen.
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: The file physically exists at the physical path?

Comment: This is perhaps a dumb question, but do you have a file found at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ called `phpinfo.php`? On another note (this should not cause the error you have above), but does it have `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` within it?

Comment: I don't have it there... but what I would like to see the phpinfo, it should be there somewhere right? and I can't write anything into that C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

Comment: Ok, so you're saying there is no file found at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ called phpinfo.php? How can it open a file that doesn't exist in the location it's looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EquinoX, create a directory called C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testsite, and in that directory put a file called test.php which contains

<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

You should then be able to run this by typing

http://localhost/testsite/test.php

in your browser window.